# Get specific categories in wordpress for current post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to achieve the following without luck.

I have the next categories in wordpress:

```
Book (level 1)
    Chapter 1 (level 2)
        Article 1 (leve 3)
        Article 2 (leve 3)
        Article 3 (leve 3)
    Chapter 2 (level 2)
        Article 1 (leve 3)
        Article 2 (leve 3)
        Article 3 (leve 3)
```

All my posts has 3 categories, one for each level. What I want is get just the category on level 3 in the current post and use it in the header of my page, but also I want get the category on level 2 and use it in the sidebar.

I have tried the function `get_the_categories()`, but it show me all the categories parents and childs and I cannot choose just one in a specific level.

My code is this:

```
function proof( $atts ) {

    $categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
        'parent'  => 0,
        'hierarchical' => 0,
        'depth'     => 1
    ) );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a><br />',
        esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
        esc_html( $category->name )
    );
}

}

add_shortcode("proof", "proof");
```

Comment: Add your code here so we can see what you did and help you where you stuck

Comment: I put my code in my question, that code return me all the categories parent, but I just want the categories for the current post

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the current category using following code.

```
   $category = get_queried_object();
   $current_cat= $category->term_id;
```

and you can use that category id in your `get_categories` function

```
   $categories = get_categories( array(
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'parent'  => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 0,
    'depth'     => 1,
    'child_of' => $current_cat 
) );
```

Comment: With that code I'm geeting all the parent categories, I just want the categories applied to the current post.

Comment: what you get in $current_cat variable? is it your current post's category ?

Comment: I don't get nothing. I tried to echo the **$current_cat** but in the frontend isn't showing nothing

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying with this code that allows me to get the parent category

```
///Function to get the parent category  
function parent( $atts ) {
    global $post;

    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);

    $top_cat_obj = array();

    foreach($categories as $cat) {
        if ($cat->parent == 0) {
            $top_cat_obj[] = $cat;  
        }   
    }   

    return $top_cat_name[0]->name;
}

add_shortcode("parent", "parent");
```

Afterwards, I used almost the same code to get the children of that category:

```
function children( $atts ) {
global $post;

$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);

//get top level category of current post
$top_cat_obj = array();

foreach($categories as $cat) {
    if ($cat->parent != 0) {
        $top_cat_obj[] = $cat;  
    }   
}   

return $top_cat_obj[0]->name;
}

add_shortcode("children", "children");
```